# how to remove magento notification widget

Tags: php, magento, widget

I'm new to magento,I'm trying to hide notification widget, this widget contains latest messages and notifications from extensions, I know how to hide latest messages but I can't find a way to hide extensions messages, can any one tell me where can I find this widget an how to control it?
thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have any custom module installed you can add in your etc/modules XML file

`<Mage_AdminNotification>
    <active>false</active>
</Mage_AdminNotification>`

Comment: thanks for respond, I've tried this and it removed only latest messages and extension notifications still in place :(

Comment: any idea .. any help !!

Comment: A better way to do this is:
Go to System --> Configuration --> Advanced

Here disable Mage_AdminNotification and save config.

A non technical person can also do this.

Comment: After making changes in the xml files make sure you clear the caches.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Admin Notifications:

1. Navigate to *System > Configuration*
2. In the sidebar, click *Advanced > Advanced*
3. Open the *Disable Modules Output* section
4. Select "Disable" for *Mage_AdminNotification*
5. Click "Save Config"

Keep in mind that disabling the notifications will also disable you ability to navigate to the "Inbox" by going to *System > Notifications*.